# Battery not charging above 34% on Lenovo E430

Tags: 12.04, laptop, lenovo, battery

My System Spec is: OS: ubuntu 12.04 LTS OS Type: 64-bit Laptop Model: Lenovo Thinkpad E430.

My Laptop is plugged to the wall for more than 10 hours. But the battery percentage never goes above 34%. Restarting the PC does not help.

I removed the plug and used the PC until the battery was completely drained. But after plugging it to wall. The battery is still stuck on 34%. What can be the problem and what needs to be done further?

Answer (score 0):

The battery reached his end of lifecycle and needs to be replaced. Don't try to overcharge it, it can even explode!

Comment: This is a month old laptop. Anything else?

Comment: Take it back than! It is still in warranty.

Comment: No Lenovo service center in my vicinity. This is what I tried:1. Discharged the battery completely. 2. Removed the battery and charged it again. It charged till 100% this time. 3. Next day I used the laptop for a while and started to charge again. It is now stuck on 71%. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps try it under other OS, see if it charges. I still suspect that the battery is faulty. Can you post on pastebin the output of dmesg?

Comment: Here it says that a bios update can resolve the issue. It worth to try: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/Plugged-in-not-charging-on-t400-t410-and-e430/td-p/850615

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ysu40w01. No BIOS update available for Linux. I checked here - http://support.lenovo.com/en_IN/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&DocID=HT073272

Comment: Bios update's software is made just for Windows. You have to use that, eventually freedos.